# Error running timer using ac-slime

Tags: auto-complete-mode, slime

Using `ac-slime` I am getting the following errors:

`Error running timer ‘ac-update-greedy’: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p \.\.\.) [3 times]
Error running timer ‘ac-show-menu’: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p \.\.\.)`

I re-installed all auto-complete components from Melpa because this was mentioned as solution in similar cases, without a change.

I filed an [Issue](https://github.com/purcell/ac-slime/issues/15) but the original author of `ac-slime` is not using `auto-complete` any more. I tried to find something in the source which could cause this but my elisp knowledge is just too limited. As far as I can see, there was no change in `auto-complete` for years, so I have no idea why this happens and how it could be solved.

Is anyone using `ac-slime` or should I switch to `company`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause for this issue: Somehow my `ac-comphist.dat` was corrupted and therefore led to this error for some candidates. I cleared the file and everything works fine again.